# how to deal with array subscript warning in C when using isxdigit()?

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-warnings, ctype

I have the following code in C:

```
char input[127] = "hello world";

isxdigit(input[0]);
```

but I got the following warning:

```
warning: array subscript has type 'char'
```

What is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: The reason: `isxdigit()` appears to be implemented as a lookup table, i. e. an array of bitmasks. The fix: I think you can safely ignore this, or cast the character to `int`.

Comment: @imsiso Huh what? That's just normal array initialization... Don't teach others C until you aren't aware of fundamental language constructs...

Comment: @imsiso `char input[127] = "hello world";` is a perfectly valid initialization of a `char` array. See C99 6.7.8:4 and 6.7.8:14 “An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.”

Comment: [Related...](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/998347_353292554774051_378902926_n.png)

Comment: thanks everybody and sorry its been a long time I had not update myself or read about C. again sorry.|-:

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that in your C implementation, `isxdigit()` is implemented as a macro using an array lookup.

As long as your input string contains only characters <=127 you can fix it either with a cast:

```
isxdigit ((int)input[0]);
```

or, if you think casts are ugly, with the aid of a benign expression, such as adding 0:

```
isxdigit (0 + input[0]);  /* Avoid cast by using an int-typed expression. */
isxdigit (+input[0]);     /* Same thing using unary plus instead of addition. */
```

Since the C Standard requires that `isxdigit` also be a function, you can alternatively call the function instead of the macro:

```
(isxdigit)(input[0]);
```

or even

```
#undef isxdigit
isxdigit(input[0]);
```

This should produce no warning, since `input[0]` is promoted to `int` (assuming a prior `#include <ctype.h>`.)

As cmaster rightfully points out, these solutions break down once your `char` is signed and contains negative values. In that case you must first cast to `unsigned char` (and then to `int` if you want).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `isxdigit` has prototype `int isxdigit(int)`. So to remove this warning you should explicitly cast argument to `int`

```
isxdigit((int)input[0]);
```

Comment: Although the cast will help, your answer does not explain the reason for the warning at all.

Comment: No, this is not the reason. `char` is implicitly promoted to `int` when passed to a function. The real reason is what I and @Jens explained.

Answer (score 2):

The point is, that the standard does not define whether or not the type char is signed, leaving this decision to the implementation. As such `(int)(char)128` may either evaluate to 128 or -128. The latter is obviously bad for array indices, as your compiler noticed (smart guy, that compiler).

So the correct fix is to cast to `unsigned char`, not to `int`.

```
isxdigit((unsigned char)input[0])
```

If you go with the other, wrong answers, you may end up crashing on utf8 strings! (utf8 uses codes greater than 127 for multibyte characters.)

Edit: Of course, Pascal Cuoq is right in saying, that such an implementation would not be allowed to implement isxdigit as a table lookup macro, however, what I said applies to any occurence of this compiler warning, including any lookup table you implement on your own. It is very unfortunate that the signedness of char is not defined, and one should better know about this issue and know to avoid it correctly.

Comment: A compilation platform that makes programs crash when `isxdigit()` is applied to a `char` is broken. I do not see what you are saying.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The point is that using isxdigit with values outside of EOF and 0...255 is *undefined behavior*. If you use it with -128 (=CHAR_MIN), the array access of the macro is quite out of bounds and may access an unmapped page in virtual memory causing a SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Jens The answer in the duplicate made me understand it. I will vote to close this one, as the answer there seems quite good.